# solving a hardcore limit with product

Tags: limits, contest-math, infinite-product

Can this expression be simplified? $$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\prod^{\frac{1}{x}-1}_{i=1}\frac{1}{\sec\frac{xi\pi}{2}}\right)^x$$

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer:  Yes.

Longer Answer:

1. Rewrite sec in terms of cosine
2. Use the fact that $y = e^{\log (y)} $ is continuous to change the product to a sum.
3. Recognize that in the limit of the sum converges to a definite integral.
4. Evaluate the integral.
5. I think the answer might be 1/2, assuming no algebra errors on my part.

Comment: Can you explain further point 3? I'm interested :)

Comment: Write down the summation you get from 2.  Look at it, and realize that the summation looks like f(k/n x) where k is ranging from 0 to n-1, that's a Riemann Sum, and for a well behaved function (which cos is) converges to the integral.